# NodeJS: Query Database Command with Loop condition

Tags: sql, node.js

I want to run a PostgreSQL database query command with condition OR to filter object by an ID Array.

`var id_arr = [1, 2, 3]`

Result I want to get:

`SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3`

I tried but it gets syntax error:

```
var querydb = `SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE ` + for (var i of id) { return id = i } + 'OR'
```

How can I write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
var ids = [1,2,3]
var querydb = `SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE id IN (${ids})`;
```